# Does anyone know what is the type of this hash?

Tags: oracle, security, hash, oracle10g, password-encryption

My friend give me a oracle server 10g, And he's changeling me If I get the password for the DATABASE or change it using SH, The server will be mine
So I've try hard because this is the first time using oracle so when I looked at the server and explore its file I found hash password , Probably will lead me to the password, this file located in this path

```
Apache/modplsql/conf/dads.conf
```

And the hash that I found start with this symbol
 @ a      `PlsqlDatabasePassword @XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX= Random letters and numbers

and its end with

```
==
```

At the beginning I thought it's sort of BASE64 Encode, And turned out to me its not

So my Question How can decode this hash? Can I get the password clearly?
also how can I modify the password of DATABASE (:
something else, I google it and some of them wrote that oracle web server 9g
using Encode64 .
Best Regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it's a one-way hash, which means you can't decrypt it.

If you're fortunate your pal won't have deleted the backup version of the `dads.conf` file (it'll be in the same directory, with a date in the name).

Otherwise, you're stuck in the position of anybody else trying to hack into a database.  Guessing or brute force.